# Upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04.1, can't access some websites (403 forbidden)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, permissions, apache2

I upgraded my server to 14.04.1. After I restarted Apache, I discovered that some of my sites are not accessible (403 forbidden). The common denominator is that they are my Drupal sites and a group of Wordpress (multisite) sites. A pair of other WP (multisite) sites in a separate directory are working.

If I type the base URL as an IP address, e.g., 66.210.xxx.xx, in my browser, I get a DB error: I cannot connect to the database because: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

It's a LAMP VM, hosted remotely, so I only have SSH access. I *did* turn off root access with password over SSH when I did the package upgrade; don't know if that's related. I don't login as root, so I didn't think I needed it.

The other noteworthy thing is that before I could start Apache, I had to edit my v-hosts.conf files, because they had this:

```
<Directory "/path/to/site">
    allow from all
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I had to change the Options to:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
```

In order to restart Apache.

Answer (score 1):

After checking the logs, looking at directory permissions, making sure various DMS db configs hadn't changed, etc, I looked at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, which apparently I had allowed to be overwritten during the upgrade. The `<Directory>` sections are more restrictive than what I had, since I have different CMSs in non-standard locations, NOT `/var/www/`. Those were the sites that wouldn't let me in. Adding in directives for them (and using the new "Require all granted" syntax) & restarting Apache solved it.

Comment: Could you please add more details on the points?